# Is there a way to connect to EventHub's Kafka using kafka-node module?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I am trying to connect to EvenHub's Kafka using the more popular [kafka-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node) library, but unfortunately, I cannot get it to work. It all works fine if I use the node-rdkafka package, but this looks like is not maintained so much anymore. (I am using SASL_SSL with a connection string)

Do you know of any working examples or whether it works in at all?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Kafka-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node) to connect to Azure Event Hub is not possible, at the moment.

Kafka-node does not support SASL_SSL, which is required to connect to Event Hub.

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/482) to address this.